# Where does ObamaCare factor into the US federal tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, health-insurance

It was in the press a lot that if you fail to buy an ObamaCare health insurance you will be fined. But I just filled up my tax returns, and I didn't see this question anywhere in the forms.

So are people really fined for not buying an ObamaCare when this is required? If yes, where is this in the forms?

Answer (score 6):

Line 61 of the 2015 [Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-1040) is labeled "Health care individual responsibility."

If you are required to make a so-called "shared responsibility payment," you would do so on this line.

The IRS has a chart called [Health Care Law & Your Tax Return](https://www.irs.gov/Affordable-Care-Act/Individuals-and-Families/Health-Care-Law-and-Your-Tax-Return) that explains all the different situations you might find yourself in regarding health care and what you need to do about it on your taxes.

Comment: Also see Form 8962.

Answer (score 4):

For whatever it's worth ObamaCare is not a type of insurance or some specific plan.  People seem to be in the habit of referring to individual policies sold through one of the state or federal exchanges as an ObamaCare policy.  Healthcare reform set certain minimum benefits that must be present in all health insurance policies with some exceptions granted to grandfathered plans.

As part of a "shared responsibility" requirement all (with some narrow exceptions) citizens are required to maintain "Minimum Essential Coverage" either individually or through an employer.  Failing to maintain coverage will trigger a penalty that grows every year. For 2015 the penalty is $325 for an adult or 2% of your AGI whichever is greater.  In the event of coverage for a partial year you will pay a prorated penalty.

Starting this year there is a new tax form that you likely will have received indicating your coverage for each given month of the year.

```
1095-A: Individual coverage
1095-B: Fully insured employer plan 
1095-C: Self funded & large employer plan

In the case of a large employer offering a fully insured plan you'll 
receive both a 1095-B and a 1095-C.
```

There have been some concessions made to employers regarding these forms and as such the requirement to include a 1095-B or 1095-C with your individual taxes has been waived.  If you received tax-subsidized coverage at an exchange you should include the 1095-A you received.  In turbotax there was a quick checkbox to indicate that you had coverage for the year.